# Android use same GCM Sender ID / Project ID for different GCM Servers

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging

how is the effect, if a gcm sender / project id of the same android app is used in different gcm servers ?

Would that mean, that a push is received by different servers or would the google gcm server deny the registration ?

Comment: Before someone gives me a -1, he should also explain it. I have no clue on that subject !!! So what should StackOverFlow make sense ?

Comment: you basically mean to host the gcm service on different server with same google api key hitting to gcm isnt it?

Comment: that will not cause any issues since that api is registered for ur package name..i itslef use service hosted on dfferent servers